# Select statement not echoing out all the rows from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two database tables. My `comments` table looks like this:

```
comid | comuserid
  10      7    
  20      7    
  30      9
```

My `replies` table looks like this:

```
repid | repcomid | repfromuser | reptouser
  1       10          22             7   
  2       10          22             7
```

This is what my index.php page currently looks like:

```
comid10 (commented by comuserid1)
    [repid1] repfromuser22 to comuserid1

comid10 (commented by comuserid1)
    [repid2] repfromuser22 to comuserid1
```

My problem is that my code is ONLY echoing out `comments` rows that contain repliers, but completely skips over the `comments` rows that doesn't contain repliers. But I want ALL my `comments` rows to be echoed out even if they contain no repliers. I also want my repliers grouped together based on the commenter they've commented under. This is the real result I want achieved:

```
comid10 (commented by comuserid1)
    [repid1] repfromuser22 to comuserid1
    [repid2] repfromuser22 to comuserid1

comid20 (commented by comuserid1)

comid30 (commented by comuserid2)
```

How would I achieve that with my current code? Please help:

```
<?php
$rqid = (int)$_GET['rqid'];
$query = $conn->query("
    SELECT comments.*, replies.*, users.username
    FROM comments
    INNER JOIN replies
    ON comments.comid = replies.repcomid
    INNER JOIN users
    ON comments.comid = users.userid
    WHERE comments.comrqid = {$rqid}
");
$comreps = [];
while($row = $query->fetch_object()) {
  $comreps[] = $row;
}
?>

<?php foreach($comreps as $comrep): ?>
    <div class="rqdivc">
        <?php echo $comrep->username; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="fxrp">
        <div>
            <?php echo $comrep->repfromuser; ?> -->
            <?php echo $comrep->reptouser; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Use a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Check this "ON" expression: INNER JOIN users
    ON comments.comid = usern.userid, looks like it should be "comments.comuserid = usern.userid"

Comment: @MichaelKrutikov yeah that was a typo error - my mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested by Strawberry - Use a LEFT JOIN - resolved my issue. Thank you person!